# How to get value from dataTable of gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a girdivew and a SQLDataSource to bind the dataTable information to gridview.

How can I get the value of a certain column for the current editing row in the Row UPDATING EVENT. ( From dataTable ) .

Thank you ,

Comment: Everything I found on google and no one worked..

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried? are you trying to get data from a certain column only? or a certain ID that represents the entire row? if it is the latter, you can do the following:

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value);

}
```

you do have to state your data key name in your gridview, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

edit after user commented:

if you want a certain value from a certain column you can do this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="handler" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataKeyNames="id"  OnRowCommand="RowCommandHandler">
```

add a onRowCommand to your gridview, then in your codebehind:

```
 protected void RowCommandHandler(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
   int k = row.RowIndex;
   string text = row.Cells[1].Text;
 }
```

you get the index of the row that was selected, then you take that index and pass it to GridView1.Rows, then you have the selected row, and then you can get data from whatever column you want.

```
 string text = row.Cells[1].Text;
```

if the column you need text from is 4th, you simply change Cells[1] to Cells[4] etc.

Comment: From a certain column only . and I need it in ROW UPDATING event :( I've tried a lot ..but couldn't find something.

Comment: @Alexander: Look at my example.. this is what you want to achieve i believe

Comment: ..what the..:)) I just need to get in row updating event a value from a column...why do I need those 2 pages of code

Answer (score 0):

In example below i am display data in grid and then allowing user to acitave or deactivate comment Asynchronously. I am using UPDATE PANEL to active this Asynchronously.

You need to use both rowDataBound and RowCommand events to achieve this

This way you can get the id of the row and dow what ever you want to do with the row either edit, Delete or do something like i am doing in this example i am updated **one COLUMN**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvSHowMostViewedArticles"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
         AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="920px" BackColor="White" 
         BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
         Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Black" 
         GridLines="Horizontal" PageSize="10"   onrowdatabound="gvSHowMostViewedArticles_RowDataBound" 
onrowcommand="gvSHowMostViewedArticles_RowCommand" onpageindexchanging="gvSHowMostViewedArticles_PageIndexChanging">

         <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sno">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleTitle" HeaderText="Article Title" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Name" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnShowMessage" runat="server" Text="Read" CommandName="showMessage" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activate">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnActivateComment" runat="server" Text="Activate" CommandName="ActivateComment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="De Activate">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDeActivateComment" runat="server" Text="De-Activate" CommandName="DeActivateComment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                         </asp:TemplateField>
```

```
        protected void gvSHowMostViewedArticles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show Message
            LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnShowMessage") as LinkButton;
            if (lb != null)
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);


            //Activate
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                LinkButton lbActivate = e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnActivateComment") as LinkButton;
                if (lbActivate != null)
                    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lbActivate);

                lbActivate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +
                "confirm('Are you sure you want to Activate this comment " +
                DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") + "')");
            }
            //De Activate
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                LinkButton lbActivate = e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnDeActivateComment") as LinkButton;
                if (lbActivate != null)
                    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lbActivate);

                lbActivate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +
                "confirm('Are you sure you want to De-Activate this comment " +
                DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") + "')");
            }
        }


      protected void gvSHowMostViewedArticles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show Message
            if (e.CommandName == "showMessage")
            {
                int sno = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                string strSql = "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE comID = " + sno;
                DataSet ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
                lblCommentMessage.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["comMessage"].ToString();
            }

            // Activate Comment
            if (e.CommandName == "ActivateComment")
            {
                int sno = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                String strSql = "UPDATE Comments SET Visible = 1 WHERE ID = " + sno;
                DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
                lblCommentMessage.Text = "Activated";
            }

            // De Activate Comment
            if (e.CommandName == "DeActivateComment")
            {
                int sno = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                String strSql = "UPDATE Comments SET Visible = 0 WHERE ID = " + sno;
                DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);

                lblCommentMessage.Text = "Deactivate";

            }
        }
```

Comment: @Alex: In above code i am updated one COLUMN I believe this is what you want to do.

Comment: ..what the..:)) I just need to get in row updating event a value from a column...why do I need those 2 pages of code

Comment: @Alex: If will study the code you will find the solution.. Stackoverflow is not meant for ready made solution you have to put an effort at least. You already have few solutions..